Why is my law of total expectation approach wrong for this problem?
I am trying to solve the following question: "Anna and Brenda are playing a game. They repeatedly toss a coin. Anna wins if 3 heads appear. Brenda wins if 3 tails appear. The heads and tails do not need to be consecutive. What is the expected number of coin tosses for a winner to be determined?"
Here is my approach, but I do not know why it is wrong. Assume that ${X}$ represents the number of tosses, ${A}$ represents the event that Anna wins, and ${B}$ represents the event that Brenda wins. By the law of total expectation, we have that ${\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X|A]P[A]+\mathbb{E}[X|B]P[B]}$. I also know that he game can only last 3,4, or 5 flips, since it takes at least 3 flips to determine a winner and 3 heads/3 tails must have appeared by the 5th flip.
I start with finding ${\mathbb{E}[X|A]}$. It's easy to see that ${P[3|A]=\frac{1}{8}}$, as only HHH would lead to victory.
For 4 flips, of the 16 possible permutations of 4 coin flips, the last flip must be heads, and the 3 flips before it must contain 2 heads and 1 tail (i.e. HHTH). Therefore, we have that ${P[4|A]=\frac{\binom{3}{2}}{16}=\frac{3}{16}}$. For 5 flips, of the 32 possible permutations of 5 coins flips, the last flip must be heads, and the 4 flips before it must contain 2 heads and 2 tails. Therefore, ${P[5|A]=\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{32}=\frac{6}{32}}$. So, ${\mathbb{E}[X|A]=\frac{1}{8}(3)+\frac{3}{16}(4)+\frac{6}{32}(5)=\frac{66}{32}}$
I believe that Brenda's case is symmetric to Anna's, since the situation is exactly the same except now it's tails instead of heads. So, ${\mathbb{E}[X|B]=\mathbb{E}[X|A]=\frac{66}{32}}$
Finally, I believe that ${P[A]=P[B]=\frac{1}{2}}$ since, as I mentioned before, the cases are symmetric. Putting it all together, I get that ${\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{66}{32}}$. However, the actual answer is double this value, ${\frac{33}{8}=4.125}$. I have seen another question on Stack Overflow asking about this question, and I can understand why the answer is indeed 4.125 (using a different method). However, what I cannot understand is why my answer is incorrect. I have checked my method many times, but I cannot seem to find a mistake. I would greatly appreciate any assistance is this matter.

When you're computing $P[n|A]$, you're actually computing $P[n \cap A]$. For instance, $HHH$ is the outcome that leads to the game ending in 3 turns and Anna winning. The conditional probability is actually $$P[n|A] = \frac{P[n \cap A]}{P[A]} = \frac{1/8}{1/2} = 1/4$$
The failure to divide by $1/2$ leads to the off-by-a-factor-of-two error.

Thank you so much. This makes sense to me now.
